# Why does Silverlight claim that font height is in pixels, when IT'S NOT?

Tags: silverlight, font-size

All of the documentation I can find, and every search I do, keeps coming back with the assertion that in Silverlight, when you set a FontHeight it's a height in pixels, and likewise for LineHeight, in e.g. a TextBlock.  But in practice that isn't true at all: when I set a font height (and line height) of 22 with a common font like Lucida Sans Unicode, the actual height between lines is 33 pixels.  (Actually, 33 and a fraction.)

To work around this, I tried doing what I had done in Java applets: use font metrics to ask how tall my text actually is.  The only way to do this that I found is to render the sample text into an offscreen TextBlock, Measure it, and see how tall it ends up.  It returned a very handy answer: 32 pixels.

Note that this is ALMOST correct.  The onscreen TextBlock rendered the font 33 pixels high, and the offscreen one rendered it 32 pixels high.  The only way to measure my text accurately turned out to be to put the "offscreen" block onscreen, transparent and behind the real onscreen one.  Then the measurement returns 33.

What am I missing here?  Why does everybody say the height is in pixels, but I find that the number here represents an actual height measured in pixel-and-a-halfs, and furthermore the exact ratio varies depending on whether the control is part of the active page or is detached and self-sufficient?  What am I not understanding??

*Added note*: I am aware of the difference between the height occupied by a row of text and the height of the actual glyphs.  But the same documentation that says the font height is in pixels also says that the line height is in pixels, and defaults to being the same as the font height.  This clearly implies that the font height is supposed to include all vertical space used, not just the glyph heights.

---

*Final note*: I think my problem in the end is that I keep running into misinformation about silverlight, and then forgetting where I read it, so I get it mixed up with the accurate information.  Like, where was it that I read that Canvas stretches to hold its content?  It doesn't.

Comment: A font is measured in typographic points. No one say anything about pixels.

Comment: The following pages each say "in pixels":

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.fontsize%28v=VS.95%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189010%28vs.95%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwf9s90b.aspx) is some explanation of the "font size" concept.

I've created the example of the text with the size of 200 pixels. Yellow rectangle has the size of 200 pixels too:

```
<Rectangle Height="200" Width="96" Fill="Yellow" />
<TextBlock FontSize="200" FontFamily="Arial" Text="ÂSj" />
```

[image]

- Ascent (the height of Â) = 180 pixels,
- Descent (space below Â and S) = 50 pixels,
- Internal leading (circumflex above Â) = 30
  pixels
- Font height = ascent + descent = 180 + 50 = 230 pixels
- Font size = font height - internal leading = 230 - 30 = 200 pixels

As you see, the actual height of a font of 200 pixels is 230 pixels. Accordingly, a font of 22 pixels has the actual height 33 pixels.

Conclusion: accents above letters are not included in the **font size**, but they are included in the **font height**.

Comment: Then why oh why does Silverlight documentation state that by default, the LineHeight is equal to the FontSize??  I explicitly set the LineHeight as well as the FontSize to 22, and it comes out to 33.  Or rather, to 33 and a fraction... doing accurate metrics requires using floating point.

Comment: You may well ask, when it comes out to 33 pixels, what is the height of letters?  It is..... 18.  What about with descenders?  21.  So maybe that's in the right ballpark, but then LineHeight should be very different from FontSize.

Comment: @PaulKienitz As it is said "an effective line height based on FontSize plus an offset". But actually this property is used for multiline textboxes and doesn't change the text size at all. See the Remarks section in this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.lineheight%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: Aha, it's ignoring the LineHeight because I was using the other LineStackingStrategy.

Answer (score 2):

font height is 1,5 times capital-height in typography

Use the grid on this page http://www.studentsportfolio.nl/10pxGrid/